# How is the puppet osfamily core fact determined?

Tags: puppet

I am working with puppet 2.7.19 with facter 1.6.0 on a Suse 11 Linux machine.  The `$::osfamily` facter variable is unset, though it does have the `$::operatingsystem` fact set:

```
$ puppet apply -e 'notify { "$::osfamily/$::operatingsystem": }'
notice: /SLES
```

How is the `$::osfamily` fact set in puppet?  I imagine that upgrading to later versions of puppet would solve this, but upgrading on this Suse distribution is difficult.

One workaround is to set the facter variable globally (say in /etc/profile):

```
$ export FACTER_OSFAMILY=suse
$ /usr/bin/puppet apply -e 'notify { "$::osfamily/$::operatingsystem": }'
notice: suse/SLES
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to get this set?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one approach you could take. Create a module within your puppet tree, call it `my_facts` (for example).

Then create the following `my_osfamily.rb` (fact) file in `modules/my_facts/lib/facter/my_osfamily.rb`

```
Facter.add("my_osfamily") do
    setcode do
        os = Facter.value('operatingsystem')
        case os
        when /CentOS|RedHat/
            "redhat"
        when "Ubuntu"
            "debian"
        when "FreeBSD"
            "freebsd"
        when "Darwin"
            "osx"
        else
            os
        end
    end
end
```

Now assuming you have [pluginsync](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/plugins_in_modules.html#enabling-pluginsync) enabled on your puppet nodes, your custom fact should automatically propagate and you should be able to use the `$::my_osfamily` fact as needed.

Depending on how your environment is setup, you could also query your facts using:

```
# facter -p | grep my_osfamily
```

Comment: +1 for some new ideas to try, but I'm not clear on a few things. I need $::osfamily set because that is what a third party (puppetforge) module uses, so $::my_osfamily doesn't help. More importantly, how do I ensure that the above new fact(s) are read in before this third party module executes?  What is the incantation to make this fact appear before other modules "run" via "include" in a node definition?

Comment: I didn't realize you needed `$::osfamily` specifically - in that case rename the above fact to `osfamily` or use the [real osfamily](https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter/blob/master/lib/facter/osfamily.rb) code. Assuming you have pluginsync enabled, these facts (along with any other custom facts) will be the first thing read in before your manifests are applied. You don't have to `include` this module or any of that. It's designed to 'just work'.

Comment: Unfortunately, the setup I'm working on doesn't use agents or pluginsync. We just run `puppet apply manifests/site.pp` off a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the answer of how facter/puppet sets the `$::osfamily` fact, and I don't know why facter version 1.6 doesn't set it.  But I was able to find a suse rpm for facter 1.7.  After upgrading, the `$::osfamily` fact is now set to "Suse" so that solves the immediate issue.